# Building Openvino for Android using Cmake

Tags: android, cmake, openvino, cmake-gui, intel-myriadx

I tried to build openvino for Android devices (arm64) using Cmake, to do that I followed the following steps:

Operating system: **Ubuntu 20**

1 - I installed OpenJDK 8 using:

```
sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
```

2 - I downloaded the android NDK for linux using:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r20-linux-x86_64.zip
```

3 - I cloned the OpenVINO and OpenVINO Contrib repositories using:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules --shallow-submodules --depth 1 --branch=2021.4.1 https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino.git
git clone --recurse-submodules --shallow-submodules --depth 1 --branch=2021.4 https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_contrib.git
```

4 - I built openvino using cmake:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DTHREADING=SEQ -DIE_EXTRA_MODULES=../../openvino_contrib/modules  -DBUILD_java_api=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../android-ndk-r20/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=24 -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DENABLE_SAMPLES=OFF -DENABLE_OPENCV=OFF -DENABLE_CLDNN=OFF -DENABLE_TESTS=OFF -DENABLE_GAPI_TESTS=OFF -DENABLE_BEH_TESTS=OFF -DENABLE_PYTHON=OFF .. && make --jobs=$(nproc --all)
```

**Expectations**:

As many tutorials showed it I was expecting a file called `inference_engine_java_api.jar` to be generated in this path: `openvino/bin/aarch64/Release/lib/`

**Results:**

I didn't get any file which has `_java_api` in its name.
I just got some `.so` and `.a` files like: `inference_engine_c_api.so` and `inference_engine_legacy.so`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to install: scons in ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scons
```